# Call specific Command in combination with argument in Latex

Tags: macros

I am trying to call a specific command in combination with a argument given. The Idea is to spimplify a tedious and (semi)repetaive command.

Example what I mean:

**\newcommand{\HelloA}{something specific}**

**\newcommand{\HelloB}{something else specific}**

**\newcommand{\HelloC}{something extra specific}**

**...**

**\newcommand{\HelloZ}{something super weird}**

**\newcommand{\SomeCommand}[1][2][3]{\Hello#1 \Hello#2 \Hello#3}**

With the last command I want to call my "\Hello[...]" command by giving it the "Name" or characters needed to complete the command.
-> I would like to write:

**\SomeCommand{A}{C}{Z}**

->and it sould execute my \HelloA, \HelloB and \HelloZ command

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: yes!!! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with property lists.

You can define a property list based on an arbitrary name, in the example `Hello` and populate it.

Then you can extract the items by key.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makelist}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name
  % #2 = key-value pairs
  \prop_new:c { g_simsalabim_list_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { g_simsalabim_list_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\getfromlist}{+O{~}mm}
 {% #1 = optional separator, default a space
  % #2 = list name
  % #3 = list of keys
  \simsalabim_list_get:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__simsalabim_list_get_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \simsalabim_list_get:nnn
 {
  % clear the temporary sequence
  \seq_clear:N \l__simsalabim_list_get_seq
  % populate it by cycling over the last argument
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__simsalabim_list_get_seq
     {
      \prop_item:cn { g_simsalabim_list_#2_prop } { ##1 }
     }
   }
   % output the items with the desired separator
   \seq_use:Nn \l__simsalabim_list_get_seq { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makelist{Hello}{
  A=something specific,
  B=something else specific,
  C=something extra specific,
  Z=something super weird
}

\begin{document}

With spaces: \getfromlist{Hello}{A,C,Z}

Paragraphs

\getfromlist[\par]{Hello}{Z,B,A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: if an item contains either a comma or an `=` character, you have to use braces like below

```
X={math, $a=b$},
```

If you need to add to lists (or replace values), you can do as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makelist}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name
  % #2 = key-value pairs
  \prop_new:c { g_simsalabim_list_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { g_simsalabim_list_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name
  % #2 = key-value pairs
  \prop_gput_from_keyval:cn { g_simsalabim_list_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\getfromlist}{+O{~}mm}
 {% #1 = optional separator, default a space
  % #2 = list name
  % #3 = list of keys
  \simsalabim_list_get:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__simsalabim_list_get_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \simsalabim_list_get:nnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__simsalabim_list_get_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__simsalabim_list_get_seq
     {
      \prop_item:cn { g_simsalabim_list_#2_prop } { ##1 }
     }
   }
   \seq_use:Nn \l__simsalabim_list_get_seq { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makelist{Hello}{
  A=something specific,
  B=something else specific,
  C=something extra specific,
  Z=something super weird
}
\addtolist{Hello}{
  X={math, $a=b$},
  Y=whatever,
}

\begin{document}

With spaces: \getfromlist{Hello}{A,C,Z,X}

Paragraphs

\getfromlist[\par]{Hello}{Z,B,A,Y}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your LaTeX installation is up to date (`2022-06-01` version) you can do

```latex
\newcommand{\SomeCommand}[3]{\UseName{Hello#1} \UseName{Hello#2} \UseName{Hello#3}}
```